# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to send a dm to a specific user with the command .dmtest, but whenever I run the command I get the error mentioned in the title
Here is my code:

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands
import os
import requests
import asyncio



from keep_alive import keep_alive

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('.dmtest'):
    user = client.get_user(384185404510961664)
    # await message.author.send(...)
    await message.channel.send('test worked')
    await user.send('a')

keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Error:

```
line 78, in on_message
  await user.send('a')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Comment: You haven't enabled any intents at all, take a look at: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Answer (score 2):

<s>After playing around with your code a bit, I found that I got DMed "a" after replacing `await user.send('a')` with `await message.author.send('a')`. After making that change, the line `user = client.get_user(384185404510961664)` is unnecessary, and can be deleted.</s>

EDIT: Since this isn't what you're looking for, I dug around the internet and found that you just needed to replace `client.get_user(id)` with `await client.fetch_user(id)`.

Comment: The thing is I want to be able to dm a specific user, instead of the person who ran the command. My next plan (once I can get this to work) is to have an input for the user to choose the ID of the person they want to dm.

Comment: Alright. I'm fairly new to discord.py myself, so I'll go through the docs myself. I understand you're trying to send a dm to the user with the ID 384185404510961664?

Comment: well for the moment but I want to change it later on so you can choose who to DM

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I updated the answer with something that works for you.